# JQuery JEditable stay in edit mode on error

Tags: jquery, jeditable

I'm successfully using jeditable to submit via a function using
jQuery.ajax and the async : false option , but am having an issue
aborting if an error is returned.

How can I get the edit box to stay activated and / or revert back to
the original value if there are errors? I'm returning http status
codes.

so something like

```
async : false .ajax submit here...
if (xhr.status == 200) {
  return value;
else {
  alert ('returned error');
  // keep edit box activated but available for another try, or revert back to original value
}
```

I tried not returning a value from the function, which keeps the edit
box activated and ready for another submit, but then the ESC key
doesn't work anymore and if I click outside the edit area, the edit
box stays.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this helps in your situation, but jeditable has a reset method in it...

try...

this.reset();

this will revert the element back to display mode with the original value.

Answer (score 0):

To stay in editmode,just set response header "HTTP 404"  and render a error text.

PHP:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
echo "Error Text";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

`$(this).editable("disable");`

This should stop your errors from being editable, not sure about reverting back. I am kinda fighting the same issue with reverting back right now, but i know nothing about JavaScript...