# jeditable, how to persist edit mode

Tags: jquery, jeditable

I'm working with Jeditable and want to keep the element in edit mode based on an error return type (post-server side validation). This question has been asked before, but it doesn't seem to have ever been answered satisfactorily. Does anyone who is familiar with Jeditable have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: could you link back to the similar question asked before?

Comment: here is at least one similar [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727973/jquery-jeditable-stay-in-edit-mode-on-error)

Comment: Seriously? None of the jquery ninjas out there have ANY ideas? I was wondering if, at the very least, I could throw an event in the Jeditable callback to trigger it anew, but I don't know if that's possible or what the syntax may look like. (client side scripting newb :-/)

Comment: it usually helps if you provide more details on what you have tried, and some code

Answer (score 1):

I would just trigger jeditable event again in the callback function.  Like this http://jsfiddle.net/wgjV4/

Answer (score 0):

I just struggled with the same issue. By looking at the source code I found the following piece:

```
var onerror  = settings.onerror  || reset;
```

The default behavior obviously resets the form. In order to keep the edit after an error, you can do this

```
$('.content').editable('/some-url', {
      onerror: function() {
        alert("ERRROOOORRRR");
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the onblur setting: `onblur:function(){ return false; }`